# Setting the maximum clock speed

Tags: pi-3, overclocking

I found a lot of search results for overclocking the Raspberry Pi.

In my case, I want the opposite: I need the Raspberry to run at a constant, more predictable speed, even if it's a "slow" frequency which avoids overheating.

How do I set my 3B+ to a constant speed of say 600 MHz?

Comment: You can specify which governor is used. The default on-demand throttles back on low load but there is a fixed mode.

Comment: to set a constant speed in `config.txt`, you could `arm_freq=600` and `arm_freq_min=600`

Comment: While you can install whatever utility you like, there is no need. As the comment above states, you simply need to edit `/boot/config.txt` and set `arm_freq=600` as shown.

Answer (score 2):

easy option is to use  [cpu-frequtils](https://wiki.debian.org/CpuFrequencyScaling#With_cpufrequtils)

```
sudo apt install cpufrequtils
```

With `cpufreq-info` you will get an info on what frequencies and governors are possible for your cpu.

Then set the governor to powersave to have the cpu running at the lowest frequency all the time. (according to [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt) governor description)

```
sudo cpufreq-set -g powersave
```

or if you wanna have more control, just set the frequency settings for min (-d) and max (-u) (here both set to 600 MHz - the min frequency for a raspberry 4).

```
sudo cpufreq-set -u 600MHz -d 600MHz
```

check again with `cpufreq-info` if your settings been applied the way you wanted to. Also note the limits of the governor 'userspace', which will be applied when you use this command (at least on the RaspPi).

See this [How To](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_use_cpufrequtils) on the other possible parameters.

**Set the frequency at boot**

To set the setting at boot time you can use the deamon `cpufreqd` (seperate package, see its manpage) or use `sysfsutils` (I copied this info from [here](https://wiki.debian.org/CpuFrequencyScaling#With_cpufrequtils))

```
apt install sysfsutils
```

The sysfs values will be configured in /etc/sysfs.conf.

Here is an example for the conservative governor:

```
# by default it's 444, so we have to change permissions to be able to change values
mode devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/conservative = 644
devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/conservative/freq_step = 10
devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/conservative/up_threshold = 45
devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/conservative/ignore_nice_load = 1
devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/conservative/sampling_down_factor = 10
```

I myself wrote a small python script to change my cpu-frequency with just a click. Give me a shout if you'd like to have it.

**Info**

As I've just seen [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt): cpufrequtils will be replaced in the future by `linux-cpupower' - at least in Debian.
So you might consider using this instead. (no idea yet how to use it though)

Comment: Not sure if the above is an error or if it has changed but I had to use this to install (drop the dash) `sudo apt install cpufrequtils`

Answer (score 2):

In `/boot/config.txt`

```
arm_freq=600
```

`arm_freq` sets the maximum speed that the CPU can run at.

And the term you are looking for to call this is *underclocking*.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the current governor at `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`

I don't know of any tool to set governor, but
`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors` will show supported values
`conservative ondemand userspace powersave performance schedutil`

These can be changed by setting the scaling_governor to one of the supported values

`/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/` has lots of settings which you can examine.

The on-demand on the Pi4 shows

```
scaling_max_freq            
1500000
scaling_min_freq
600000
```

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/overclocking.md shows some documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve **constant** frequency, this is what I tried:

- Install linux-cpupower: `sudo apt install linux-cpupower`
- Check the info: `cpupower frequency-info`
- Set the governor to `userspace` so that we can set the frequency: `sudo cpupower frequency-set --governor userspace`
- Set the maximum frequency: `sudo cpupower frequency-set --max 600MHz`
- Check the info: `cpupower frequency-info`.

It should say: "**Current policy: frequency should be within 600 MHz and 600 MHz.**"